# How can I make the application never close and execute a procedure every hour?

Tags: c#, for-loop, stored-procedures, while-loop, console-application

How about!, someone could help me with this please, what I'm looking for is that through a console application every time the "00" minutes (that is, every hour), the stored procedure is executed only once (I do not know why it runs more than 1 time, since it is an insertion procedure)and I also want the application never to close, later I want to create a service and execute more procedures, but I need this for while. What am I doing wrong ?, the idea is that in the console write "Waiting for insertion in batch" and when the time comes, execute the procedure and write "Successful insertion", then keep typing "Waiting for insertion in batch" until the next hour arrives.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading;

namespace Job_StoreProcedure
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection
                  ("Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=VIDEOJUEGOS;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                for (int i = 0; i - 1 < i++; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for insertion in batch");
                    if (DateTime.Now.ToString("mm") == "00")
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_virtualX", conn);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (rdr.Read())
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Successful insertion");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Better option is to remove the loop and create normal program. The ln schedule it using windows or any other schedulers to run every hour. Making program to wait and never exit is bad idea

Comment: @PriyeshKumar They already posted that.  The question is how to do it "for now" in a console application.

Comment: The computer will be paid at the end of the day, in the end I want to return the .exe in a service that starts when the computer is turned on and the console application starts working, as I said, for now it is only with a stored procedure, but I plan to add more jobs, but I want to have the structure armed. Can you help me?

Comment: Have you considered simply scheduling the stored procedure using SQL Server Agent?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments best way to meet your needs is remove the loop and perform the operation only once, and create a task schedule to run the program on required time.

If you need to continue with same approach some of the problems which this code must be facing:

Each hour it would insert more than once if insert operation takes less than a minute. Example: say if the insert starts at 1:00:00 and finishes at 1:00:20, the program will start next iteration and would insert again because mm is still 00. One of the solution is to put the thread to sleep for 1 minute from inside of outer loop.

You will face one more problem with this code that connection would close when remains unused for some time. Also when insertion fails program will exit because of no error handling. You might want to open and close connection while performing operation (i.e. inside loop), and use error handling to keep the application running in case of exception.

Comment: Also you can use observer design pattern to create scheduler from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the timers.

```
using System.Timers;
//...
class Program
{
    private static Timer MainTimer = new Timer(1000 * 60 * 60);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for insertion in batch");

        MainTimer.Elapsed += MainTimer_Elapsed;

        // Wait for the start of the hour. Then start the one-hour MainTimer. 
        var tmptimer = new Timer() { Interval = 1000 };
        tmptimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.Minute == 0)
            {
                MainTimer.Start();              
                tmptimer.Stop();
                MainTimer_Elapsed(null, null);  // Call manually first time 
            }
        };
        tmptimer.Start();

        while (true)
            Console.Read();
    }

    private static void MainTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection ("Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=VIDEOJUEGOS;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_virtualX", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Successful insertion");
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for insertion in batch");

        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This becomes considerably easier if you adopt `async`/`await` and use `Task.Delay`:

For instance, you can:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args) //async Main supported in C#7
{
    var now = DateTime.UtcNow; //always use UTC, calculating timezones costs time
    var startOfCurrentTimePeriod = 
        new DateTime(now.Year, 
                     now.Month, 
                     now.Day, 
                     now.Hour, 
                     now.Minute, 
                     now.Second, 
                     0,         //set this ms part to 0
                     DateTimeKind.Utc);
    var triggerTime = oClock.AddSeconds(1); //when we want to run our action
    while (true)
    {
        var waitTime = triggerTime - DateTime.UtcNow;
        if (waitTime > TimeSpan.Zero) //if we have a negative wait time, just go
        {
            await Task.Delay(waitTime);
        }
        triggerTime = triggerTime.AddSeconds(1); //set the next time
        //perform action
        Console.WriteLine($"the time is : {triggerTime}");
    }
}
```

It should be trivial to convert this code to trigger on the hour rather than on the second. A good exercise.